# Get Key and Value types from dictionary in generic method

Tags: c#, generics

Id like to be able to work with Dictionaries in generic methods. What Im looking for is a way to get the Type from Key and Value of the dictionary sent to the generic extension method LoadProperty.

This is what I've done so far.

I call the method as an extension

```
entityObject.LoadProperty<Dictionary<string, int>>("CartonThreshold")
//entityObject.LoadProperty<Dictionary<string, double>>("CartonThreshold")

// ... 

public static T LoadProperty<T>(this EntityObject entity, string name) where T : new()
{
    EntityObjectProperty prop = entity.Properties.Single(x => x.Name.Equals(name));

    // If request dictionary
    if (typeof(T).GetInterface(typeof(IDictionary<,>).Name) != null || typeof(T).Name.Contains("IDictionary"))
    {
        var dictionaryInstance = (IDictionary)new T();

        // Just for testing
        var a = dictionaryInstance.Keys.GetType().Name;
        var b = dictionaryInstance.Values.GetType().Name;

        var key = (T) Convert.ChangeType(prop.Name, typeof (T));
        var value = (T) Convert.ChangeType(prop.Value, typeof (T));
        dictionaryInstance.Add(key, value);
        return (T) dictionaryInstance;
    }

    // default
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(prop.Value, typeof(T));
}
```

The goal is to return a correctly typed dictionary

Comment: Sorry, but I am having hard time to understand what do you want to achieve. Why do you need to return `Dictionary` when you are only dealing with a single property? Perhaps try to post classes `EntityObject`, `EntityObjectProperty` and to rephrase the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to clarify a bit

Comment: Added some extra code in the method for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for was the GetGenericArguments() extension of GetType()

The method below will return what I need.

```
public static T LoadProperty<T>(this EntityObject entity, string name) where T : new()
{
    EntityObjectProperty prop = entity.Properties.Single(x => x.Name.Equals(name));

    try
    {
        // If request dictionary
        if (typeof(T).GetInterface(typeof(IDictionary<,>).Name) != null || typeof(T).Name.Contains("IDictionary"))
        {
            var dictionaryInstance = (IDictionary)new T();

            var typing = dictionaryInstance.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
            Type keyType = typing[0];
            Type valueType = typing[1];

            // dictionary fallback, set to default of the valuetype if null
            object value = prop.Value != null ? Convert.ChangeType(prop.Value, valueType) : Activator.CreateInstance(valueType);
            var key = Convert.ChangeType(prop.Name, keyType);
            dictionaryInstance.Add(key, value);
            return (T)dictionaryInstance;
        }

        if (prop.Value != null)
        {
            // default
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(prop.Value, typeof(T));
        }
    }
    catch { }
    return default(T);
}
```

This way I can call the method like this

```
// Will return a typed dictionary with the EntityObjectProperty name as key and the EntityObjectProperty Value as value
entityObject.LoadProperty<Dictionary<string, int>>("CartonThreshold")

// Will return a string of the EntityObjectProperty Value
entityObject.LoadProperty<string>("CartonThreshold")

// Will return an Int of the EntityObjectProperty Value
entityObject.LoadProperty<int>("CartonThreshold")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, what you would like to do is define your method like this:

```
public static T LoadProperty<T,TKey,TValue>(this EntityObject entity, string name) 
    where T : IDictionary<TKey,TValue>, new() {
    EntityObjectProperty prop = entity.Properties.Single(x => x.Name.Equals(name));
    T t = new T();
    t.Add((TKey)prop.Name, TValue(prop.Value));
    return t;
}
```

Then call it with

```
Dictionary<string,int> property = entityObject.LoadProperty<Dictionary<string,int>, string, int>("test");
```

The bad thing is that you have to specify all the generic parameters each time...
If it's ok for your concrete case, it would be much simpler like this:

```
public static IDictionary<TKey,TValue> LoadProperty<TKey,TValue>(this EntityObject entity, string name) {
    EntityObjectProperty prop = entity.Properties.Single(x => x.Name.Equals(name));
    var dict = new Dictionary<TKey,TValue>();
    dict.Add((TKey)prop.Name, TValue(prop.Value));
    return dict;
}
```

**EDIT**: after your clarification, what about telling the two cases apart by the number of generic arguments?

```
public static IDictionary<TKey,TValue> LoadProperty<TKey,TValue>(this EntityObject entity, string name) {
    var d = new Dictionary<TKey,TValue>();
    // add value from EntityObject 
    return t;
}

public static TValue LoadProperty<TValue>(this EntityObject entity, string name) {
    TValue ret;
    // get value from EntityObject 
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Actually, couldn't you leave out `T` and just return an `IDictionary`?

Comment: Im not only interested in working with Dictionaries, if I want to type the value of my entityObject as a string Im only going to enter <string> and so on.

Comment: @Trikks Well, if it can be a string, how can you `Add(key, value)`?

Comment: See my own answer for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just define your method like this:

```
public static IDictionary<K, V> LoadProperty<K, V>(this EntityObject entity, string name)
```

Comment: I'd define an overload method then.

Comment: @Trikks - I still think overloading(which will work because of the different number of generic parameters) is a cleaner separation than using reflection and if statements, that basically split a single method's body into 2 - even the return types are different.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working with almost anything, you could pass a function to create whatever return type you want:

```
public static T LoadProperty<TKey,TValue,T>(this EntityObject entity, string name,  Func<TKey,TValue,T> createWhatever) 
{
    EntityObjectProperty prop = entity.Properties.Single(x => x.Name.Equals(name));
    return createWhatever((TKey)prop.Name, (TValue)prop.Value);
}
```

This would be a bit more verbose at the calling, though.