# Getting a specifically typed Dictionary with a generic method c#

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

First off - I appologize if this is a duplicate question.  I did search for the answer, however I'm a self-taught programmer and I don't understand some of the higher-level terms used and so may have comletely missed the actual answer.

Now, my question;
I'm trying to use a Generic method to return a typed dictionary.  Here is the code I'm using.

```
public Dictionary<string, WorkerValues>     workerValues        = new Dictionary<string, WorkerValues>();
public Dictionary<string, ValueRefValues>   valueRefValues      = new Dictionary<string, ValueRefValues>(); 
public Dictionary<string, LevelValues>      levelValues         = new Dictionary<string, LevelValues>();

public static T getGainer<T>(string value) where T : GainerValues, new() {
return current.getGainerSub<T>(value);  // current is a singleton instance of the class.
}

public static void setGainer<T>(string value, T gain) where T : GainerValues,     new() {
    current.setGainerSub<T>(value, gain);
}

public T getGainerSub<T>(string value) where T : GainerValues, new() {
    Dictionary<string, T> table = getTable <T>();
    if (!table.ContainsKey(value)){
        table.Add (value, new T());
        table[value].setID(value);
    }
    return (T) table[value];
}

public Dictionary<string, T> getTable<T>() where T : GainerValues, new(){
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(WorkerValues))      return workerValues;     //  Error Here
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ValueRefValues))    return valueRefValues;   //  Error Here
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(LevelValues))       return levelValues;      //  Error Here
    return null;
}
```

If T is WokerValues, the Dictionary Returned is `<string, WorkerValues>`, However I get an error when compiling;

`"c:\Users\Aquamentos Games\Documents\Idle Artificer\Assets\Scripts\Data.cs(51,51): Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,IdleArtificer.WorkerValues>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,T>' (CS0029) (Assembly-CSharp)"`

The compiler doesn't know that 'T' will be 'WokerValues' when I'm trying to return that value.

Originally I had the dictionaries typed as `<string, GainerValues>`, which worked.  However, for reasons specific to my implementation I had to change them (it has to do with the way I am loading and saving data between sessions - the dictionaries need to be the appropriate Type.)

Alternatively, there a better way to do this? (Keeping in mind that I need the Dictionary types to be the same as here, `Dictionary<string, GainerValues>` works in the code but it doesn't work for the Saving/Loading API I am using.

I think this thread is similar to my question;
[Get Key and Value types from dictionary in generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362119/get-key-and-value-types-from-dictionary-in-generic-method)
However, he seems to be trying to do something slightly different (or I don't understand his example code or the answers)

I thought about converting the Dictionary using the answer here;
[Converting a Dictionary from one type to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507804/converting-a-dictionary-from-one-type-to-another)
However if I am unsure if that is the 'same dictionary' or if it is a new dictionary (IE - would I have to convert it back and change the dictionary entirely every time I need to add a new key)

**EDIT**  Here is the current WORKING version of the entire class, with the casting changes suggested in one answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IdleArtificer{
    public class Data {
        public static Data current = new Data();    

        public Data(){
            // constructor with no parameters needed for I/O API
            // also why where T : new() in generic methods
        }

        public Dictionary<string, WorkerValues>     workerValues        = new Dictionary<string, WorkerValues>();
        public Dictionary<string, ValueRefValues>   valueRefValues      = new Dictionary<string, ValueRefValues>();
        public Dictionary<string, LevelValues>      levelValues         = new Dictionary<string, LevelValues>();

        public static T getGainer<T>(string value) where T : GainerValues, new() {
            return current.getGainerSub<T>(value);
        }

        public static void setGainer<T>(string value, T gain) where T : GainerValues, new() {
            current.setGainerSub<T>(value, gain);
        }

        public Dictionary<string, T> getTable<T>() where T : GainerValues, new(){
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(WorkerValues))      return workerValues as Dictionary<string, T>;
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(ValueRefValues))    return valueRefValues as Dictionary<string, T>;
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(LevelValues))       return levelValues as Dictionary<string, T>;
            return null;
        }

        public T getGainerSub<T>(string value) where T : GainerValues, new() {
            Dictionary<string, T> table = getTable <T>();
            if (!table.ContainsKey(value)){
                table.Add (value, new T());
                table[value].setID(value);
            }
            return (T) table[value];
        }

        public void setGainerSub<T>(string value, T gain) where T : GainerValues, new() {
            Dictionary<string, T> table = getTable <T>();
            if (table.ContainsKey(value))           {   table[value] = gain; }
            else                                    {   table.Add(value, gain);}
        }
//I can't save enums, so I convert them to/from strings.  Int might have 
//been better, but I've been changing the order of my enums to sort them, so 
//that would mess up any saved data if I make any changes to the order.
        public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value) where T : struct, IConvertible
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
            return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
        }

        public static WorkerValues getWorkerValues(string s){
            return getGainer<WorkerValues>(s);
        }
        public static ValueRefValues getValueRefValues(string s){
            return getGainer<ValueRefValues>(s);
        }
        public static LevelValues getLevelValues(string s){
            return getGainer<LevelValues>(s);
        }

        public static WorkerValues getWorkerValues(resource res){
            return getWorkerValues(res.ToString());
        }
        public static ValueRefValues getValueRefValues(valueRef res){
            return getValueRefValues(res.ToString());
        }
        public static LevelValues getLevelValues(level res){
            return getLevelValues(res.ToString());
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: What is `current`, can you mark the line on which the compiler fails?

Comment: You need to use back ticks "`" to make text inside <> show up. I edited the question to do so but your edit removed them.

Comment: I see that my edit removed the backticks, and I re-fixed them.  Thanks  Also marked the line where the compiler fails.  current is a singleton instance of the class.

Comment: Why are you making a generic method anyway? Making 3 methods that return each own type makes more sense.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: programming convenience, but as specified in the answer, it is not really good design to do so, since now the programmer must guarantee the type system is safe whereas in the other case the compiler can help.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes - I should have made 3 separate methods.  When I originally wrote it I was using `Dictionary<string, GainerValues>` (which all of the used types inherit).  I later found out that didn't work with my I/O API and was trying to figure out the best way to convert my code.  My I/O API only saved the properties of the GainerValue base class, and not the higher level class' properties.  Thus, I needed to rewrite it.

Comment: @ShivaFang: why do you update your question with new code? Is it still not working?

Comment: @CommuSoft It is working - I'll add a note.  I updated it to explain to one of the answereres why what he was suggesting wasn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this code shows all signs of bad code design (*bad smells*), it is adviseable to refactor it.

So the problem is that C# can't derive at compile time that when you type:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(WorkerValues))      return workerValues;
```

that a dictionary `Dictionary<String,WorkerValues>` is actually also a `Dictionary<String,T>`. This might look weird, but complex reasoning about code is in many cases not what a compiler is supposed to do. Humans reason like "*Haa, the if statement succeeds, so now we know `T` is guaranteed to be a `WorkerValues`*". A compiler only sees "*If that statement succeeds - I don't know what it means - the program is supposed to return that.*". Compilers (and code contract verifiers exist that can perform a more advanced analysis, but the C# standard is not to do that).

You can't use *Linq*'s [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method, because that would make a copy of the dictionary. This is expensive and adding elements will not get reflected to the original dictionary. You can however use a cast:

```
public Dictionary<string, T> getTable<T>() where T : GainerValues, new(){
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(WorkerValues))      return workerValues as Dictionary<string,T>;
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ValueRefValues))    return valueRefValues as Dictionary<string,T>;
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(LevelValues))       return levelValues as Dictionary<string,T>;
    return null;
}
```

(add `as Dictionary<string,T>` after every `return` statement.)

The `as` operator will perform a "safe" cast in the sense that if the can't be converted to a `Dictionary<string,T>` it will return `null`. But as said before, this kind of mixed *compile-time* and *run-time* generics are a source of a lot of trouble.

For this example, it will work, but it is not good design to perform such operations.

Comment: Sheesh.  Such a simle answer.  It works, Thanks!  I didn't consider a cast with T.  As far as the bad code design - I'm completely self-taught as a programmer, so that's why.